# Looking for a short sf story (Analog or Asimov's) about a ?Jansen/Janson? door that one could step through into the future

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, isaac-asimov

The story was probably published between 1980 and early 1990s. The technology, i.e., ?Jansen or Janson? door, was named, I believe, after a lady scientist.

Comment: Since Jansen is a real-life manufacturer of doors, it may be hard to research this. :)

Comment: In Gene Wolfe's [There are Doors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Are_Doors) the protagonist steps through into an alternate universe dominated by women.

Comment: Very loose match with Harry Harrison's *One Step From Earth*.

Comment: Could it possibly be [Living Space](https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/sffaudio-usa/usa-pdfs/LivingSpaceByIsaacAsimov.pdf) by Asimov? Not quite stepping through time, but sounds sort of similar.